# Use winexe to start a Windows process

Tags: linux, windows, remote, pstools

When I'm on Windows I use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to start processes on other Windows machines. I now have the case that I want to do that from a Linux machine.

Fortunately there is [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/), a small program which should work like PsExec, just for the Linux-World. I got no problems with installing it and I'm able to start processes like cmd.exe.

The problem is that I'm not able to start a process which is visible to the Windows user. If I start calc.exe I can see that it is started in the task manager, but there is no GUI.

Question:
How is it possible to start processes that are actually visible on the Windows machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How is it possible to start processes that are actually visible on the
>   Windows machine?

A good start would be by creating the process in the session of the currently logged on user. That's usually session 1 if there's only one person logged on. If multiple people are logged on, it might be session 2 or 3 or 27.  You'd have to run code in wtsapi32.dll first to find who was connected to which session.  In modern versions of Windows, session 0 is reserved for services and system functions.

You're starting a process in session 0, therefore no one can see it.

psexec can start a remote process and let you choose a different session in which to start it, but I don't know of any Linux equivalent. I looked at the man page for winexe and it does not appear to have that option.

**Edit**: Microsoft's official stance is that launching interactive processes remotely is too big of a security risk, and so they inhibit your ability to do it... but we can still work around it if we're willing to get dirty:

```
schtasks.exe /create /S COMPUTERNAME /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /RL HIGHEST /SC ONSTART /TN "RemoteProcess" /TR "program.exe \"argument 1\" \"argument 2\""

schtasks.exe /Run /S COMPUTERNAME /I /TN "RemoteProcess"

schtasks.exe /Delete /S COMPUTERNAME /TN "RemoteProcess"
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. The schtasks-workaround looks good. I'll wait a night to see if there are other possible solutions.

Comment: works like a charm